# DNS record types: URL, CURL, HINFO, MBOXFW

Tags: dns, domain-name

When setting the DNS for a domain name I normally use `A`, `CNAME`, and `MX`. `NS` is set automatically. There is `TXT`, which is just an info field for custom values like SPF.

Wikipedia has the following info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types

Now I see different other options, and I'm wondering what exactly they do or how they differ.

- URL
- CURL
- HINFO (probably obsolete)
- MBOXFW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MBOXFW is similar to the CURL record type. It contains a redirect/alias to another email address:

`technicalsupport@itcrowd-support.co.uk MBOXFW roy@itcrowd-support.co.uk`

This will redirect email to technicalsupport@itcrowd-support.co.uk to roy@itcrowd-support.co.uk. This has to be done by the sending MTA, and it might not support this behaviour.

URL has a similar meaning to what rxt describes.

As you probably know, since these record types aren't in any RFC, it's not a good idea to use them for production purposes.

Comment: Thank you. Any idea how URL differs from CURL?

Comment: From [powerdns-users](http://osdir.com/ml/network.dns.powerdns.user/2004-12/msg00001.html):
I noticed the same awhile ago on my nameserver at work. As it was explained to me by Bert, it's a separate record type so that the script that does the redirection can implement so-called "cloaked URL" records. This is something that EasyDNS lets you do, so that the URL that the client pulls up stays in the URL field of the window, but the URL that it redirects to is pulled up in an IFRAME, or using JavaScript or something along those lines, as opposed to a simple Location: header redirect.

Comment: Thanks again. So URL is a redirect, and CURL is a cloaked redirect which keeps the domain name in the address field of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

URL is used to redirect the domain name to another URL, which can be another domain, or a specific page with parameters etc.

CURL stands for Cloaked URL. This is not the Curl Linux tool that can fetch files. You can set another URL including path and parameters. When the (sub)domain is loaded in the browser, the Curl URL is loaded in an iframe served by the domain ISP (or using javascript with similar effect), while the URL in the browser stays at that value.

Example:

- domain: www.abc123.com
- curl for this domain: www.def456.com/xyz?a=10

When you open www.abc123.com, you see www.def456.com/xyz?a=10, and when you click on links, it stays at the def456.com domain, displaying content from abc123.com.